# Ie6*lat isnt it the same as 1000000*lat?

Tags: android

```
package ntryn.n;


import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;


public class ntryn extends MapActivity

{
    private MapView mapView;
    private MapController mc;

    GeoPoint p, p2, p3, p4;
    List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
    Drawable drawable, drawable2 , drawable3, drawable4;
    HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay, itemizedOverlay2 , itemizedOverlay3, itemizedOverlay4;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

{
try{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.main);


/* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */

LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();

mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);

// enable Street view by default
mapView.setStreetView(true);

// enable to show Satellite view
// mapView.setSatellite(true);

// enable to show Traffic on map
// mapView.setTraffic(true);
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

mc = mapView.getController();
mapView.setStreetView(true);
//mapView.setSatellite(true);
mc.setZoom(12); 
addOverLays();
}
catch(Exception e){
    Log.d("eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee",e.getMessage());
}
}
public void addOverLays(){
    String [] coordinates = {"30.084262490272522","31.33625864982605" ,"30.084123015403748", "51.5002" , "-0.1262","31.337149143218994"};
    double lat = 30.084262490272522, lat2 = 51.5002,lat3=30.084123015403748;
    double log = 31.33625864982605, log2 = -0.1262,log3=31.337149143218994;

    p = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (log * 1E6));
   p2 = new GeoPoint( (int) (lat2 * 1e6), (int) (log2 * 1e6));
   p3=new GeoPoint( (int) (lat3 * 1000000), (int) (log3 * 1000000));
    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ballon);
   drawable2 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dotred);
    drawable3 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);

    itemizedOverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable,this);
    itemizedOverlay2 = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable2,this);        
    itemizedOverlay3 = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable3,this);    
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(p, "Cairo", " over1");
   OverlayItem over2 = new OverlayItem(p2, "ulm", "over2");
    OverlayItem over3 = new OverlayItem(p3, "offff", "over3");

    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);

    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

    itemizedOverlay2.addOverlay(over2);
   mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay2);

    itemizedOverlay2.addOverlay(over3);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay3);
 mc.setZoom(17); 
 //mc.animateTo(p);
}


/* Class My Location Listener */



public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener

{

@Override

public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)

{





    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(    (int) (loc.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
            (int) (loc.getLongitude() * 1E6));
//DoubletoString(loc.getLatitude());

//DoubletoString(loc.getLongitude());


String Text = "My current location is: " +

"Latitud ="+ loc.getLatitude() +

"Longitud =" + loc.getLongitude();


Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),

Text,

Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
mc.animateTo(point);

}



private void DoubletoString(double latitude) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)

{

Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),

"Gps Disabled",

Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

}


public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)

{

Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),

"Gps Enabled",

Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}


public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)

{


}
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}

}/* End of Class MyLocationListener */


@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}


}


/* End of UseGps Activity*/
```

it force close. this due to the 3 overlaying items when i add only 2 in other words remove the p3 which is * 1000000. it's work, but with it it doesn't zoom and when i want to zoom it show force close

Comment: I do not understand the question. Please clean it up.

Comment: Why  p3=new GeoPoint( (int) (lat3 * 1000000), (int) (log3 * 1000000)); force close!! whats wrong with it ?!! its only show the map but when i press the zoom its Not responding and forse close !! and when i remove p3 !! its work fine and the zoom work whats wrong !! Urgent i neeed help

Comment: And another -1 for kid-style writing ("onlyyyy") and other annoyances like repeated exclamation marks.

Answer (score 1):

`1e6` is a floating point number, `1000000` is an integer.

```
[adrian@cheops3:~]> cat Test.java
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("1e6 = " + 1e6);
        System.out.println("1000000 = " + 1000000);
    }
}
[adrian@cheops3:~]> javac Test.java && java Test
1e6 = 1000000.0
1000000 = 1000000
```